# Evaluation of a certain area

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I asked a version of this question on Math Stack Exchange 6 days ago, but without any responses: [The area of a certain region](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4747254/the-area-of-a-certain-region)

I am interested in evaluating the area of the region defined by

$$A_{L_1, L_2, F} = \left \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \left \lvert L_1(x,y) L_2(x,y) F(x,y)^2 \right \rvert \leq 1 \right\}$$

where $L_1, L_2$ are linearly independent forms and $F$ is a positive definite quadratic form.

If the square was not there, then the answer of this question can be given explicitly in terms of elliptic integrals; see my paper [On binary cubic and quartic forms](https://jtnb.centre-mersenne.org/item/10.5802/jtnb.1083.pdf) and this paper of Bean: [The practical computation of areas associated with binary quartic forms](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2153771).

Specifically, I am interested in the case when $L_1(x,y) = y, L_2(x,y) = x + 7y, F(x,y) = x^2 + xy + 7y^2$.